# my linux command is "ps -C opmn | awk 'NR >4 {print $4}'"

Tags: awk, subprocess, ps

```
import subprocess

opmn = "ps -C opmn | awk 'NR >4 {print $4}'"
subprocess.call(opmn, shell=True)

Nmanager = "jps | grep Node | awk '{print $2}'"
subprocess.call(Nmanager, shell=True)

AMservers = "ps -ef | grep java | awk '{print $13}' | grep 'Dweblogic.Name' | sed 's/^.\{16\}//g' | sort -n"
subprocess.call(AMservers, shell=True)
```

I am getting the output, however, I need to store the output in a datastructure like list or dict and further check the condition is true for each output.

I need to convert this into python program and save it in one variable and check the condition.

Output should be stored like this

```
dict = {'opmn_stat' : 'opmn', 'Nmanager_stat' : 'Nmanager', 'Aserver_stat':'Aserver'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `subprocess.check_output` to get the output into a variable in Python.

For example

```
import subprocess
ps_cmd = "ps"
ps_output = subprocess.check_output(ps_cmd, shell=True)
print(ps_output)
```

This will fetch the output of the `ps` command as a string into `ps_outout` variable. You can further process this to however you want it to be.

Comment: I tried using that, however, python 2.6.6 does not have that feature